# Bash Script to find large files recently modified in the past 24 hours

Tags: linux, bash, diskspace

How can I search through a massive amount of data (28TB) to find the largest 10 files in the past 24 hours?

From the current answers below I've tried:

`$ find . -type f -mtime -1 -printf "%p %s\n" | sort -k2nr | head -5`

This command takes over 24 hours which defeats the purpose of searching for most recently modified in the past 24 hours.  Are there any solutions known to be faster than the one above that can drastically cut search time?  Solutions to monitor the system also will not work as there is simply too much to monitor and doing such could cause performance issues.

Comment: Use find command with size and age criteria

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to do this when working with terabytes of data?

Comment: Question still too broad? @TobySpeight

Comment: Much better - although possibly only borderline on-topic here.  Voting to re-open.  The total size is unlikely to make much difference to performance, but the total number of files almost certainly will (and, to some extent, how they are gathered into directories and filesystems).

Comment: Assuming this isn't a one-off (or you'd be posting to [unix.se] or [sf]), then you may be better served by observing file creation/write/deletes as they happen, using `inotify()` or similar, and maintaining a database of files' last modification and size.  It seems redundant, but you can give the database table a suitable index to answer your query much more efficiently.  And you might even be able to do it with Bash - though a compiled language may be your best choice.

Comment: @TobySpeight that's an interesting approach.  So basically using inotify in tandem with a db to monitor modification and file size.  Unfortunately inotify is not an option as it isn't on my server and I don't have the option of getting it there.

Comment: @TobySpeight I've thought about the inotify approach a little more and monitoring 28 TB of files would take a drastic performance hit on the server.  It may even bring down the server having it running all the time

Comment: It doesn't depend at all on the total size - if you select your events sensibly, it depends only on how many files are written, how often.  But it's your choice; it remains an option.

Comment: @TAsk I've update my question.  Please let me know if this is still too broad

Comment: @Cheesebaron  I've update my question. Please let me know if this is still too broad

Comment: @jakerella I've update my question. Please let me know if this is still too broad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this?

```
$ find . -type f -mtime -1 -printf "%p %s\n" | sort -k2nr | head -5
```

top 5 modified files by size in the past 24 hours.

Comment: I agree this works but I'm not sure it's the best in terms of efficiency and scaling through terabytes of data

Comment: find is a compiled command, in C. If you're using linux that's very fast. The size don't matter (file are not opened), it's the number of files that matter.

Comment: @MikeSallese: what makes you think it's not efficient?

Comment: @nickgrim it's currently been running for over 2 hours.  For all I know that may be efficient. I'm not claiming it is or it isn't I'm just searching for the most efficient way to do this.  I'm working with 28 TB of data

Comment: More than the data size, the number of files/directories matter.

Comment: @Sinkingpoint 28TB or not efficient/not efficient still exist.  My goal is to maximize efficiency

Comment: Part of the inefficiency of this approach is that you are sorting the entire result, even though you are keeping only the first few results.  You probably need to write a `sort` that drops the excess unwanted lines as new input comes in.  This will keep the working set to a reasonable size.  I guess this boils down to finding a shell equivalent to SQL's `ORDER BY size DESC LIMIT $max`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the standard yet very powerful `find` command like this (`start_directory` is the directory where to scan files)

```
find start_directory -type f -mtime -1 -size +3000G
```

`-mtime -1` option: files modified 1 day before or less
`-size +3000G` option: files of size at least 3 Gb